# Force certain operations to evaluate last

Tags: hold, order

I have an integral of a term which first needs some massaging, e.g. (EDIT: Made the integral in such a way that it cannot be pulled out)

```
Integrate[f[x](Integrate[g[x,y],{y,0,x}]*Integrate[h[x,y],{y,-1,0.3x}]),x]
```

where `f[x]=Sum[a[i] T[i, x], {i, 0, 10}]` and `g[x,y]=Sum[a[i,j] T[i, x] T[j, y], {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}]` (Similarly `h`). I wrote it in this way to reference [Truncation by coefficient size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297018/truncation-by-coefficient-size) .

The coefficients are numerical and I will, after taking their product, chop the products of coefficients after a certain size. **After** this has been done I want to replace `T` by the actual functions and evaluate the integrals.

Doing this using `Hold` does not produce the desired result, since `Chop`of a product won't work unless expanded, however `Hold`precisely forbids the product to expand. And I also have two `Holds`if I naively just put hold around the `Integrate`.

How would I best proceed? Any way to tell Mathematica that I want **only** the Integrate to evaluate last, but still be able to take products and other operations on the integrands?

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your problem, but perhaps you are looking for [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) instead of `Hold`?

Comment: I also don't understand what you're asking. Can you maybe walk through part of the "massaging" process? And why don't you just do this "massaging" before you take the integral?

Comment: @lericr The massaging in question is described in the second paragraph. I essentially need to truncate the product of series expansions to a certain order. The reason I cannot do this before integration is because I cannot pull out the integral completely, since some terms in the actual expression are not part of it. (It's a nested integral with sums etc.) And inserting the integrals to the final expression is not viable, since all terms get mixed up.

Comment: I'll try `Inactive` today and come back to you. Thanks for the hint, looks promising. @Domen

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather busy at the moment, maybe tomorrow. @Domen

Comment: Unfortunately, Inactive also seems to freeze operations on the integrand: E.g. `Inactive[Integrate][
 Expand[Inactive[Integrate][(x + y)^3, {x, 0, y}] - y^3], y]` does not cancel the `y^3`

Comment: @Confuse-ray30, how could `Expand` even do that without performing integration? Also, if you want to expand things deeper inside, you have to use `ExpandAll`.

Comment: Good question... that was stupid of me. It's really hard to come up with a situation that isn't too complicated. I'll probably just use Daniel Hubers code and see if truncation works.

Answer (score 1):

You may write your integral like:

```
Integrate[f[x]g[x,y],{y,0,x}],x]
```

Now you can expand f[x]g[x,y] and truncate. E.g.:

```
SeedRandom[1];
a[i_] := RandomReal[{0, 1}]
a[i_, j_] := RandomReal[{0, 1}]
g[x, y] = Sum[a[i, j]  T[i, x]  T[j, y], {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}];
f[x] = Sum[a[i]  T[i, x], {i, 0, 10}];
Chop[Expand[f[x]  g[x, y]], 1.3]
```

Then you can replace T[..,..] by the real function: fun. If you want to write this in one single statement:

```
Integrate[Chop[Expand[f[x]  g[x, y]], 1.3] /. T[i_, x] -> fun[i, x], {y,x},x]
```

Comment: Sorry, my minimal working example really doesn't capture the difficulty, I'll try to edit my question in such a way to make these types of manipulations impossible. (Unless of course it still works, then good for me.)